# Page on VPS in Laravel doesn't work

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.1, vps

I bought VPS and installed on it Laravel, main page working normal and I getting subtitle "Laravel 5" but when I created test page, in route file:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
   return 'test' ;
});
```

I getting this:

```
 Not Found
 The requested URL /test was not found on this server.
 Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at plerp.net.pl Port 80`
```

I chmod storage folder on 777.

`

```
    ServerName www.plerp.net.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/laravel>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

`

Comment: Have you enabled the `mod_rewrite` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your web server does not have the rewrite module activated. Try this (beware, Apache only instructions below):

- `sudo a2enmod rewrite` (for Debian/Ubuntu family)
- `sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/httpd/mods-enabled/` (for Red Hat / CentOS family)

It might not be installed, in which case you'll need to search for it in the distribution's repositories:

- `sudo apt search apache rewrite` for deb-based distros
- `sudo yum search httpd rewrite` for rpm-based or `sudo dnf search httpd rewrite` for Fedora 21+

then install it with

- `sudo apt install <name-of-package>` for deb-based
- `sudo yum install <name-of-package>` for rpm-based (replace `yum` with `dnf` for Fedora 21+)

You might want to double check on file and folder permissions, most probably all you need to do is to `chown` the respective folder under the web server's user.

Comment: I did rewrite and is the same problem, when i restarted i got:
 `* Restarting web server apache2
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 155.xxx. Xx. Xx. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
   ...done.` i chmoded folders into storage.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your `sites-enabled` directory somewhere? In every file in there should be a line defining **ServerName**, which is nothing else than the domain name you want to access using that definition (i.e. example.org, which should lead to Laravel's home – look after the `DirectoryRoot` directive)

Comment: Ok, i did it, i copied apache file from tutorial from digital ocean and everything working https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-4-on-a-centos-6-vps